# Filtering for the Infinite Scroll list does not work in Django

Tags: django, ajax

I'm trying to implement filtering for my infinite scroll list in Django. My example looks like this:

**views.py**

```
def search(request):
    search = Influencer.objects.all()
    #get data
    media = request.GET.get('media', False)
    popularity_compartment = request.GET.get('popularity_compartment', False)
    if media:
        search = search.filter(media=media)
    if popularity_compartment:
        search = search.filter(popularity_compartment=popularity_compartment)
    #paginator
    paginator = Paginator(search, 20)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    try:
        search_paginator = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        search_paginator = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        search_paginator = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    context = {'search_paginator': search_paginator,}

    return render(request, 'app/template.html', context)
```

So I have two filters that should work on my infinite list. I use them in this way in a

**template.html**

```
  <!-- Paginator with object -->
  <div class=" infinite-container">
    {% for object in search_paginator %}
    <!-- Object -->
    <div class="card mb-3 hover-shadow-lg infinite-item">
       [...]
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

  <!-- Load more -->
  {% if search_paginator.has_next %}
  <div class="mt-4 text-center">
    <a href="?page={{ search_paginator.next_page_number }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-neutral rounded-pill shadow hover-translate-y-n3 infinite-more-link">Loading...</a>
  </div>
  {% endif %}

  <!-- Infinite Scroll -->
  <script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'assets/js/infinite.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script>
  var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
    element: $('.infinite-container')[0]
  });
  </script>
```

Although my example looks complex, I think it presents a minimal configuration to show the problem. The problem is that the filter works only for the first page. If the list expands down, my filters used in the view do not work (and the list still shows items from the entire queryset instead of filtered).

I think it may have a problem with my poor understanding of ajax. I do not understand why despite the fact that `search_paginator` consists of `search.filter(media=media)` after expanding the list, it works as if it were `search = Influencer.objects.all()`.

**jquery-3.1.1.min.js**

**jquery.waypoints.min.js**

```
/*!
Waypoints - 4.0.1
Copyright © 2011-2016 Caleb Troughton
Licensed under the MIT license.
https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints/blob/master/licenses.txt
*/
! function() {
  "use strict";

  function t(o) {
    if (!o) throw new Error("No options passed to Waypoint constructor");
    if (!o.element) throw new Error("No element option passed to Waypoint constructor");
    if (!o.handler) throw new Error("No handler option passed to Waypoint constructor");
    this.key = "waypoint-" + e, this.options = t.Adapter.extend({}, t.defaults, o), this.element = this.options.element, this.adapter = new t.Adapter(this.element), this.callback = o.handler, this.axis = this.options.horizontal ? "horizontal" : "vertical", this.enabled = this.options.enabled, this.triggerPoint = null, this.group = t.Group.findOrCreate({
      name: this.options.group,
      axis: this.axis
    }), this.context = t.Context.findOrCreateByElement(this.options.context), t.offsetAliases[this.options.offset] && (this.options.offset = t.offsetAliases[this.options.offset]), this.group.add(this), this.context.add(this), i[this.key] = this, e += 1
  }
  var e = 0,
    i = {};
  t.prototype.queueTrigger = function(t) {
    this.group.queueTrigger(this, t)
  }, t.prototype.trigger = function(t) {
    this.enabled && this.callback && this.callback.apply(this, t)
  }, t.prototype.destroy = function() {
    this.context.remove(this), this.group.remove(this), delete i[this.key]
  }, t.prototype.disable = function() {
    return this.enabled = !1, this
  }, t.prototype.enable = function() {
    return this.context.refresh(), this.enabled = !0, this
  }, t.prototype.next = function() {
    return this.group.next(this)
  }, t.prototype.previous = function() {
    return this.group.previous(this)
  }, t.invokeAll = function(t) {
    var e = [];
    for (var o in i) e.push(i[o]);
    for (var n = 0, r = e.length; r > n; n++) e[n][t]()
  }, t.destroyAll = function() {
    t.invokeAll("destroy")
  }, t.disableAll = function() {
    t.invokeAll("disable")
  }, t.enableAll = function() {
    t.Context.refreshAll();
    for (var e in i) i[e].enabled = !0;
    return this
  }, t.refreshAll = function() {
    t.Context.refreshAll()
  }, t.viewportHeight = function() {
    return window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight
  }, t.viewportWidth = function() {
    return document.documentElement.clientWidth
  }, t.adapters = [], t.defaults = {
    context: window,
    continuous: !0,
    enabled: !0,
    group: "default",
    horizontal: !1,
    offset: 0
  }, t.offsetAliases = {
    "bottom-in-view": function() {
      return this.context.innerHeight() - this.adapter.outerHeight()
    },
    "right-in-view": function() {
      return this.context.innerWidth() - this.adapter.outerWidth()
    }
  }, window.Waypoint = t
}(),
function() {
  "use strict";

  function t(t) {
    window.setTimeout(t, 1e3 / 60)
  }

  function e(t) {
    this.element = t, this.Adapter = n.Adapter, this.adapter = new this.Adapter(t), this.key = "waypoint-context-" + i, this.didScroll = !1, this.didResize = !1, this.oldScroll = {
      x: this.adapter.scrollLeft(),
      y: this.adapter.scrollTop()
    }, this.waypoints = {
      vertical: {},
      horizontal: {}
    }, t.waypointContextKey = this.key, o[t.waypointContextKey] = this, i += 1, n.windowContext || (n.windowContext = !0, n.windowContext = new e(window)), this.createThrottledScrollHandler(), this.createThrottledResizeHandler()
  }
  var i = 0,
    o = {},
    n = window.Waypoint,
    r = window.onload;
  e.prototype.add = function(t) {
    var e = t.options.horizontal ? "horizontal" : "vertical";
    this.waypoints[e][t.key] = t, this.refresh()
  }, e.prototype.checkEmpty = function() {
    var t = this.Adapter.isEmptyObject(this.waypoints.horizontal),
      e = this.Adapter.isEmptyObject(this.waypoints.vertical),
      i = this.element == this.element.window;
    t && e && !i && (this.adapter.off(".waypoints"), delete o[this.key])
  }, e.prototype.createThrottledResizeHandler = function() {
    function t() {
      e.handleResize(), e.didResize = !1
    }
    var e = this;
    this.adapter.on("resize.waypoints", function() {
      e.didResize || (e.didResize = !0, n.requestAnimationFrame(t))
    })
  }, e.prototype.createThrottledScrollHandler = function() {
    function t() {
      e.handleScroll(), e.didScroll = !1
    }
    var e = this;
    this.adapter.on("scroll.waypoints", function() {
      (!e.didScroll || n.isTouch) && (e.didScroll = !0, n.requestAnimationFrame(t))
    })
  }, e.prototype.handleResize = function() {
    n.Context.refreshAll()
  }, e.prototype.handleScroll = function() {
    var t = {},
      e = {
        horizontal: {
          newScroll: this.adapter.scrollLeft(),
          oldScroll: this.oldScroll.x,
          forward: "right",
          backward: "left"
        },
        vertical: {
          newScroll: this.adapter.scrollTop(),
          oldScroll: this.oldScroll.y,
          forward: "down",
          backward: "up"
        }
      };
    for (var i in e) {
      var o = e[i],
        n = o.newScroll > o.oldScroll,
        r = n ? o.forward : o.backward;
      for (var s in this.waypoints[i]) {
        var a = this.waypoints[i][s];
        if (null !== a.triggerPoint) {
          var l = o.oldScroll < a.triggerPoint,
            h = o.newScroll >= a.triggerPoint,
            p = l && h,
            u = !l && !h;
          (p || u) && (a.queueTrigger(r), t[a.group.id] = a.group)
        }
      }
    }
    for (var c in t) t[c].flushTriggers();
    this.oldScroll = {
      x: e.horizontal.newScroll,
      y: e.vertical.newScroll
    }
  }, e.prototype.innerHeight = function() {
    return this.element == this.element.window ? n.viewportHeight() : this.adapter.innerHeight()
  }, e.prototype.remove = function(t) {
    delete this.waypoints[t.axis][t.key], this.checkEmpty()
  }, e.prototype.innerWidth = function() {
    return this.element == this.element.window ? n.viewportWidth() : this.adapter.innerWidth()
  }, e.prototype.destroy = function() {
    var t = [];
    for (var e in this.waypoints)
      for (var i in this.waypoints[e]) t.push(this.waypoints[e][i]);
    for (var o = 0, n = t.length; n > o; o++) t[o].destroy()
  }, e.prototype.refresh = function() {
    var t, e = this.element == this.element.window,
      i = e ? void 0 : this.adapter.offset(),
      o = {};
    this.handleScroll(), t = {
      horizontal: {
        contextOffset: e ? 0 : i.left,
        contextScroll: e ? 0 : this.oldScroll.x,
        contextDimension: this.innerWidth(),
        oldScroll: this.oldScroll.x,
        forward: "right",
        backward: "left",
        offsetProp: "left"
      },
      vertical: {
        contextOffset: e ? 0 : i.top,
        contextScroll: e ? 0 : this.oldScroll.y,
        contextDimension: this.innerHeight(),
        oldScroll: this.oldScroll.y,
        forward: "down",
        backward: "up",
        offsetProp: "top"
      }
    };
    for (var r in t) {
      var s = t[r];
      for (var a in this.waypoints[r]) {
        var l, h, p, u, c, d = this.waypoints[r][a],
          f = d.options.offset,
          w = d.triggerPoint,
          y = 0,
          g = null == w;
        d.element !== d.element.window && (y = d.adapter.offset()[s.offsetProp]), "function" == typeof f ? f = f.apply(d) : "string" == typeof f && (f = parseFloat(f), d.options.offset.indexOf("%") > -1 && (f = Math.ceil(s.contextDimension * f / 100))), l = s.contextScroll - s.contextOffset, d.triggerPoint = Math.floor(y + l - f), h = w < s.oldScroll, p = d.triggerPoint >= s.oldScroll, u = h && p, c = !h && !p, !g && u ? (d.queueTrigger(s.backward), o[d.group.id] = d.group) : !g && c ? (d.queueTrigger(s.forward), o[d.group.id] = d.group) : g && s.oldScroll >= d.triggerPoint && (d.queueTrigger(s.forward), o[d.group.id] = d.group)
      }
    }
    return n.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      for (var t in o) o[t].flushTriggers()
    }), this
  }, e.findOrCreateByElement = function(t) {
    return e.findByElement(t) || new e(t)
  }, e.refreshAll = function() {
    for (var t in o) o[t].refresh()
  }, e.findByElement = function(t) {
    return o[t.waypointContextKey]
  }, window.onload = function() {
    r && r(), e.refreshAll()
  }, n.requestAnimationFrame = function(e) {
    var i = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || t;
    i.call(window, e)
  }, n.Context = e
}(),
function() {
  "use strict";

  function t(t, e) {
    return t.triggerPoint - e.triggerPoint
  }

  function e(t, e) {
    return e.triggerPoint - t.triggerPoint
  }

  function i(t) {
    this.name = t.name, this.axis = t.axis, this.id = this.name + "-" + this.axis, this.waypoints = [], this.clearTriggerQueues(), o[this.axis][this.name] = this
  }
  var o = {
      vertical: {},
      horizontal: {}
    },
    n = window.Waypoint;
  i.prototype.add = function(t) {
    this.waypoints.push(t)
  }, i.prototype.clearTriggerQueues = function() {
    this.triggerQueues = {
      up: [],
      down: [],
      left: [],
      right: []
    }
  }, i.prototype.flushTriggers = function() {
    for (var i in this.triggerQueues) {
      var o = this.triggerQueues[i],
        n = "up" === i || "left" === i;
      o.sort(n ? e : t);
      for (var r = 0, s = o.length; s > r; r += 1) {
        var a = o[r];
        (a.options.continuous || r === o.length - 1) && a.trigger([i])
      }
    }
    this.clearTriggerQueues()
  }, i.prototype.next = function(e) {
    this.waypoints.sort(t);
    var i = n.Adapter.inArray(e, this.waypoints),
      o = i === this.waypoints.length - 1;
    return o ? null : this.waypoints[i + 1]
  }, i.prototype.previous = function(e) {
    this.waypoints.sort(t);
    var i = n.Adapter.inArray(e, this.waypoints);
    return i ? this.waypoints[i - 1] : null
  }, i.prototype.queueTrigger = function(t, e) {
    this.triggerQueues[e].push(t)
  }, i.prototype.remove = function(t) {
    var e = n.Adapter.inArray(t, this.waypoints);
    e > -1 && this.waypoints.splice(e, 1)
  }, i.prototype.first = function() {
    return this.waypoints[0]
  }, i.prototype.last = function() {
    return this.waypoints[this.waypoints.length - 1]
  }, i.findOrCreate = function(t) {
    return o[t.axis][t.name] || new i(t)
  }, n.Group = i
}(),
function() {
  "use strict";

  function t(t) {
    this.$element = e(t)
  }
  var e = window.jQuery,
    i = window.Waypoint;
  e.each(["innerHeight", "innerWidth", "off", "offset", "on", "outerHeight", "outerWidth", "scrollLeft", "scrollTop"], function(e, i) {
    t.prototype[i] = function() {
      var t = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
      return this.$element[i].apply(this.$element, t)
    }
  }), e.each(["extend", "inArray", "isEmptyObject"], function(i, o) {
    t[o] = e[o]
  }), i.adapters.push({
    name: "jquery",
    Adapter: t
  }), i.Adapter = t
}(),
function() {
  "use strict";

  function t(t) {
    return function() {
      var i = [],
        o = arguments[0];
      return t.isFunction(arguments[0]) && (o = t.extend({}, arguments[1]), o.handler = arguments[0]), this.each(function() {
        var n = t.extend({}, o, {
          element: this
        });
        "string" == typeof n.context && (n.context = t(this).closest(n.context)[0]), i.push(new e(n))
      }), i
    }
  }
  var e = window.Waypoint;
  window.jQuery && (window.jQuery.fn.waypoint = t(window.jQuery)), window.Zepto && (window.Zepto.fn.waypoint = t(window.Zepto))
}();
```

**infinite.min.js**

```
/*!
Waypoints Infinite Scroll Shortcut - 4.0.1
Copyright © 2011-2016 Caleb Troughton
Licensed under the MIT license.
https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints/blob/master/licenses.txt
*/
! function() {
  "use strict";

  function t(n) {
    this.options = i.extend({}, t.defaults, n), this.container = this.options.element, "auto" !== this.options.container && (this.container = this.options.container), this.$container = i(this.container), this.$more = i(this.options.more), this.$more.length && (this.setupHandler(), this.waypoint = new o(this.options))
  }
  var i = window.jQuery,
    o = window.Waypoint;
  t.prototype.setupHandler = function() {
    this.options.handler = i.proxy(function() {
      this.options.onBeforePageLoad(), this.destroy(), this.$container.addClass(this.options.loadingClass), i.get(i(this.options.more).attr("href"), i.proxy(function(t) {
        var n = i(i.parseHTML(t)),
          e = n.find(this.options.more),
          s = n.find(this.options.items);
        s.length || (s = n.filter(this.options.items)), this.$container.append(s), this.$container.removeClass(this.options.loadingClass), e.length || (e = n.filter(this.options.more)), e.length ? (this.$more.replaceWith(e), this.$more = e, this.waypoint = new o(this.options)) : this.$more.remove(), this.options.onAfterPageLoad(s)
      }, this))
    }, this)
  }, t.prototype.destroy = function() {
    this.waypoint && this.waypoint.destroy()
  }, t.defaults = {
    container: "auto",
    items: ".infinite-item",
    more: ".infinite-more-link",
    offset: "bottom-in-view",
    loadingClass: "infinite-loading",
    onBeforePageLoad: i.noop,
    onAfterPageLoad: i.noop
  }, o.Infinite = t
}();
```

Comment: "I think it may have a problem with my poor understanding of ajax", please share your ajax code.

Comment: I was editing my question, thank you for the answer